# Hot disconnected/ Neutral still connected OK?

Tags: electrical

I am replacing a range hood with a microwave. The hood was hardwired in. I ran a new 20A circuit from the panel for the microwave. The existing hood wiring is tied into the kitchen ceiling light. There were 5 wires tied together in this box. I found and disconnected the hot wire, but don't know how to ID the neutral wire running to the hood. Can I leave it connected and just cap the hood wiring off since the hot wire isn't connected?

Comment: Better to do the same thing - disconnect or cap - for all wires to avoid confusion for the next guy. Can you post a picture of the wires?

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I ended up going through one by one and found which one it was. I now have both ends of both wires disconnected and capped. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Glad we could help; would you mind posting your answer to your question, so that future visitors can benefit? Thanks.

Comment: Yes -- answer with how you solved this problem and I'll give you a +1 @FrankBullitt :)

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using trial and error to go through each neutral to figure out which one went to the range hood wire. Took a little bit of time but this way I can safely disconnect the wire and cap both ends. Might as well do it now while I have everything torn apart.